# why does heroku block http and not https

Tags: http, heroku, https

I am currently using the free version of Heroku, when deploying an app, Heroku blocked http, I changed to https which was not blocked, why does this occur? `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>`

Comment: When you say 'heroku blocked http' do you mean your browser prevented the http script from loading?

Comment: now that you ask, I'm not sure if it was my browser, thanks for the helpful reply, I'm just learning

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Heroku uses HTTPS by default which means your apps URL is given as https://myappname.herokuapp.com and when you as a user of the Internet request a web address using HTTPS what you are saying is 'I want an encrypted connection'.

Your browser therefore blocks, or at the very least warns you, when a website attempts to download non encrypted HTTP resources.

To avoid this all external linked resources in your code should use the HTTPS protocol. You can actually use a handy trick to do this by not specifying a protocol at all but instead using `//` so your script tag will look like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
```

Then it will use what ever protocol the browser uses for your website. Be is HTTP or HTTPS.